# Django livesettings - greyed out group

Tags: django, django-admin, settings, admin

I'm using [django-livesettings](http://django-livesettings.readthedocs.org) to provide additional parameters to be set by the admin.

One thing I'd like to do is have groups greyed out according to whether they've been enabled or not.

An example would be enabling either pop3 or imap mail settings, perhaps via a radio button. If the admin enables pop3 then all the imap settings are greyed out.

Another example might be just a simple group enable checkbox. If the group isn't enabled then there's no need to enter further info.

I'd like to make it clear which settings are in force. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something, you'd need to do with JS/CSS. Use a project-specific template override with [settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs) or go fork the project at [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-livesettings) and add your feature.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably fork and addthe feature.